# Silverlight - How to center a control with its parent using XAML

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In Silverlight, How could I center a control within another control (e.g. Rectangle within a Canvas) automatically without specifying the margins or horizontal/vertical alignments manually on the XAML and without writing code for that?. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for my bad english)

I don't think you can do that without any code with a Canvas as parent. If you put your Rectangle inside a Grid, you can use the VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment to align it. The Canvas is used for coordinate positioning (left, top).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wish MS would implement this through a property in the child. By the way, your English is just fine. Thanks again.